# How to post a data from a servlet in a variable to a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have performed uploading of a file to a servlet. Now I want to perform some action which will transfer me to another servlet. I have generated some string from this uploaded data and now I need to post it to another servlet which will catch that string from a variable. How to do it?

Comment: You've a design problem. Delegating the business job to another servlet is a code smell. The other servlet is apparently doing "too much". You should refactor that code into another Java class (a domain object?) which you then just import and reuse in the both servlets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can forward (server side) the request to the next servlet:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/nexturl");
dispatcher.forward(aRequest, aResponse);
```

You can attach the decoded variable to your session object and retrieve it from there in the servlet you forward to. (Or, if the servlet can be called with a parameter too, check the session for the variable (remove it when you use it) and if it's not there try to parse the apropriate parameter.)

**Update**

To use the HTTP session as a way to pass your variable, add it:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("name", "value");
```

and retrieve it in the next servlet:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String value session.getAttribute("name");
session.removeAttribute("name");
```

The session is created automatically by the servlet container, if uses a session cookie to map session state to a series of HTTP requests from the same browser session.

Comment: As an alternative to storing the variable in the session (which can cause obscure issues if the session parameter is not managed correctly), you can also [use a HttpServletRequest wrapper](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/634) to pass your string as a standard parameter to the second servlet.

Comment: Hello i have successfully redirected to another servler :)... Now can you tell me how to post a string to another servlet in a variable name "var" as become my second servlet has a getparameter("var").. I havent maintained any session... Can u explain how to use HttpServletRequest wrapper :)

Comment: @Coder_sLaY, I updated explaining how to use the session. (or have a look at the url aroth gave in his comment)

Comment: Rather set it as a request attribute. A forward just reuses the same request. Then you don't need to abuse the session.

Comment: @BalusC can u explain how to set it as request Attribue?

Comment: @Coder_sLaY, Hint: the `HttpSessionRequest` class provides a `setAttribute(String, Object)` method :-)